# Why did Stellargraph could install when I updated pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, stellargraph

I tried to install `stellargraph` in a Python 3.6.13 venv. It threw the following error:

[image]

Then I ran `pip install --upgrade pip` and re-ran the installation. It worked. I want to understand why upgrading pip was the game changer. The error related to TensorFlow had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty self-explanatory from your console output. `stellargraph` needs `tensorflow>=2.1.0` which isn't not supported by your pip version `18.1`.

So when you updated `pip` to `21.0.1`, it could find a successful distribution of `tensorflow` (>`2.1.0`) and could therefore install `stellargraph` in the correct manner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think it's self explanatory though. I should have been more clear. The yellow warning about pip version is thrown even when I issue a sucessful `pip install ...` command. It's just a general purpose warning and it is independent from the TensorFlow issue. In other words, the red error message and the yellow warning message are concatenation of independent messages in the output of pip command.